# Groovy: Method definition not expected here

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, slack

I'm sure this is a simple fix but I'm new to programming in general and Groovy in particular.

I am trying to follow [this guide](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/07/18/pipline-notifications/) to enable slack notifications in a Jenkins 2 pipeline job but pasting and customizing the final code block is giving me the following error;

```
Method definition not expected here. Please define the method at an appropriate place or perhaps try using a block/Closure instead.
```

This is my code right now, although I've substituted a few bits for security. The error is occurring at the `def notifyBuild(String buildStatus = 'STARTED') {` line.

```
node('on-demand-t2large'){
    stage ('Checkout') {
        checkout( checkout stuff here )
    }

    stage ('Build') {
        try {
            notifyBuild('STARTED')

            dir("place") {
                sh 'script name'
            } 
        }
        catch (e) {
            // If there was an exception thrown, the build failed
            currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
            throw e
        } 
        finally {
            // Success or failure, always send notifications
            notifyBuild(currentBuild.result)
        }

        def notifyBuild(String buildStatus = 'STARTED') {
            // build status of null means successful
            buildStatus =  buildStatus ?: 'SUCCESSFUL'

            // Default values
            def colorName = 'RED'
            def colorCode = '#FF0000'
            def subject = "${buildStatus}: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'"
            def summary = "${subject} (${env.BUILD_URL})"
            def details = """<p>STARTED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]':</p>
            <p>Check console output at &QUOT;<a href='${env.BUILD_URL}'>${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a>&QUOT;</p>"""

            // Override default values based on build status
            if (buildStatus == 'STARTED') {
                color = 'YELLOW'
                colorCode = '#FFFF00'
            } else if (buildStatus == 'SUCCESSFUL') {
                color = 'GREEN'
                colorCode = '#00FF00'
            } else {
                color = 'RED'
                colorCode = '#FF0000'
            }

            // Send notifications
            slackSend (channel: '@me', color: colorCode, message: summary)
        }
    } 
}
```

I understand from some googling that groovy doesn't accept inner class definition, but as new as I am to programming I don't know how to fix it. Any help (with explanations so I can learn!) would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest moving your `notifyBuild()` method definition outside the `node` and `stage` hierarchy. That is, take the last two braces at the bottom `} }` and move them up to the line above `def notifyBuild(...`. Leave the third bottom brace where it is.

Comment: @BalRog That did it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Move the `notifyBuild()` method outside the `node` and `stage` hierarchy, like so:

```
node('on-demand-t2large'){
    stage ('Checkout') {
        checkout( checkout stuff here )
    }


    stage ('Build') {
        try {
            notifyBuild('STARTED')

            dir("place") {
                sh 'script name'
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // If there was an exception thrown, the build failed
            currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
            throw e
        } finally {
            // Success or failure, always send notifications
            notifyBuild(currentBuild.result)
        }
    }
}

def notifyBuild(String buildStatus = 'STARTED') {
    // build status of null means successful
    buildStatus =  buildStatus ?: 'SUCCESSFUL'

    // Default values
    def colorName = 'RED'
    def colorCode = '#FF0000'
    def subject = "${buildStatus}: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'"
    def summary = "${subject} (${env.BUILD_URL})"
    def details = """<p>STARTED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]':</p>
    <p>Check console output at &QUOT;<a href='${env.BUILD_URL}'>${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a>&QUOT;</p>"""

    // Override default values based on build status
    if (buildStatus == 'STARTED') {
        color = 'YELLOW'
        colorCode = '#FFFF00'
    } else if (buildStatus == 'SUCCESSFUL') {
        color = 'GREEN'
        colorCode = '#00FF00'
    } else {
        color = 'RED'
        colorCode = '#FF0000'
    }

    // Send notifications
    slackSend (channel: '@me', color: colorCode, message: summary)
}
```

**Explanation:** Most Groovy DSLs do not allow declarations inside the DSL elements. It appears the Jenkins DSL is no exception.

Comment: This still does not work. I have my code structure exactly this way and I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'notifyBuild' found among steps...`

Comment: I don't know what to say, as I only posted this as a solution AFTER @Alex told me it worked. I have not actually run the code. Perhaps Alex would be interested in joining the discussion? If I had not been so explicit with my commentary and Alex had not responded so positively, I probably would not have posted this as a solution at all.

Comment: @IanD.Rossi Late answer, but all I can tell you is the non-technical answer - definitions can't be contained inside any of the node/stage steps. Your error sounds more like a typo, might be worth opening a new question.

Comment: This fails if the `@NonCPS` function is inside of `pipeline { }`.

Comment: @alex Does the Closure syntax in heroin 's answer work in that case?

Comment: @heroin take note of my question to alex above.

Comment: Indeed, for declarative pipelines, it also requires definitions to be outside of pipeline block. There it will work

Answer (score 25):

You can use Closures http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html

```
node('on-demand-t2large') {
    def notifyBuild = { String buildStatus -> 
        // build status of null means successful
        buildStatus =  buildStatus ?: 'SUCCESSFUL'

        // Default values
        def colorName = 'RED'
        def colorCode = '#FF0000'
        def subject = "${buildStatus}: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'"
        def summary = "${subject} (${env.BUILD_URL})"
        def details = """<p>STARTED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]':</p>
        <p>Check console output at &QUOT;<a href='${env.BUILD_URL}'>${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a>&QUOT;</p>"""

        // Override default values based on build status
        if (buildStatus == 'STARTED') {
            color = 'YELLOW'
            colorCode = '#FFFF00'
        } else if (buildStatus == 'SUCCESSFUL') {
            color = 'GREEN'
            colorCode = '#00FF00'
        } else {
            color = 'RED'
            colorCode = '#FF0000'
        }

        // Send notifications
        slackSend (channel: '@me', color: colorCode, message: summary)
    }

    stage ('Checkout') {
        checkout( checkout stuff here )
    }

    stage ('Build') {
        try {
            notifyBuild('STARTED')

            dir("place") {
                sh 'script name'
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // If there was an exception thrown, the build failed
            currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
            throw e
        } finally {
            // Success or failure, always send notifications
            notifyBuild(currentBuild.result)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer was not even given until almost a year after my answer was already accepted. For what it's worth, one of the upvotes is mine.